# Why clickedButtonAtIndex method is call even tap on out side of UIActionSheet?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

As my title said that `clickedButtonAtIndex` delegate method is call even tap on out side of UIActionSheet.
My actionSheet is display when I tapped on `UIButton`.
Code of my `UIActionSheet` declaration.

```
-(void)btnComplexityTapped:(UIButton *) sender
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select your complexity" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Easy", @"Medium", @"High", nil];
    [actionSheet showFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
    [actionSheet release];
}
```

And in delegate method

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)myActionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self.btnComplexity setTitle:@"Easy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [self.btnComplexity setTitle:@"Medium" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.btnComplexity setTitle:@"High" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

I know that this issue is fix by set last condition in delegate method to set `else if(buttonIndex == 1)` instead of only `else`. But I does not want to apply any fixing but I want to know **why delegate method is called even I am not tapping on any button of `UIActionSheet`**

See this video for more clear picture.

[image]

As above video default title of button is "Medium" when I click on button then actionSheet is open and I click on out side of actionSheet (such like `self.view`) then delegate method `clickedButtonAtIndex` is called so last `else` condition is become true and thats way my button's title is changed "High".

Can any body tell my why this is happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iPad action sheet is presented in a popover. No cancel button because touching out of popover is equivalent to a touch on cancel. So, your delegate receives the message as if cancel button has been touch.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is presented in `POPOVER` (**iPad**) which does not have cancel button on ActionSheet.Its `Cancel` is triggered if you tap out of ActionSheet.